# C error: storage size of 'p1' isn't known

Tags: c

```
unsigned int method(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
struct power p1,p2,p3;
unsigned int i,x=1;
struct list mult;
.
.
.
}

struct power{
int base;
int index;}

struct list{
struct power info;
struct list *next;}
```

Tengo un problema con el código:
Al intentar compilar me aparece

> /* [Error] storage size of 'p1' isn't known */

en la segunda linea de código(`struct power p1,p2,p3;`).

El mismo error ocurre con `struct list mult;`.

¿Cómo puedo arreglar estos errores?

Comment: no sobra la palabra struct al definir p1 como power?

Comment: al hacerlo me aparece lo siguiente: [Error] unknown type name 'power'

Comment: Porque ademas, en c es importante el orden al definir las cosas. El struct debe estar definido antes de usarlo

Comment: Al dejar el struct definido antes de usarlo sigue ocurriendo el mismo problema: [Error] unknown type name 'power'

Answer (score 2):

Aquí hay dos problemas:

**1. Orden de declaración**

En C es imprescindible que tipos, variables y funciones estén declarados antes de su primer uso.

Para declarar `p1` necesitas tener antes la declaración de `power`:

```
struct power
{
  int base;
  int index;
}

struct power p1;
```

**2. Las estructuras terminan con punto y coma**

Aunque cueste entender el motivo es lo que hay. Si no añades un punto y coma después de la llave de cierre obtendrás un bonito error de compilación:

```
struct power
{
  int base;
  int index;
}; // <<--- el punto y coma que no falte

struct power p1;
```

Repite estos mismos pasos para solucionar el problema con `mult`.